# How to change the triangle limit in Webots that prevents shadows from a cadshape?

Tags: webots, 3d-model

I am trying to get reasonable fidelity on a vehicle body I add as a shape to a vehicle. I model in Alias or Fusion and have good surface quality and don't want to lose that when my vehicle (robot) is the center of attention. I would like to be able to adjust the limit that Webots appears to impose by not producing cast shadows from meshes which exceed that limit. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In Webots R2023b, the limit on the maximum number of triangles in meshes for casting shadows is 65535 as documented [here](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/shape#field-summary). This limit should be sufficient for fairly high quality meshes. Unfortunately, this value is hard-coded [here](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/blob/520350ffc291b771e04e5ec96b341f9c8242da03/src/wren/Constants.hpp#L72) and cannot but changed at run-time. But luckily, since Webots is fully open-source, you can change this value and [recompile Webots from the source](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/wiki) to increase this limit.

Even better, you can contribute a new [Pull Request](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/pulls) to make this parameter an option available in the Webots Preferences, so that it can be easily changed at run-time without having to recompile Webots.

Alternatively, you may want to split your mesh into several meshes, with each individual mesh having a triangle count lower than 65536.

*Disclaimer: I am a [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots) developer working at [Cyberbotics](https://cyberbotics.com).*